# QuickBooks Online (QBO) write to Custom Fields on Invoice via v2 IPP .NET SDK in C#

Tags: c#, sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

There are three custom fields that can activated on QuickBooks Online's Invoice.
How do I write to these fields using the v2 IPP .NET SDK with C#?
I do not see any field in the header that could be used to write to these fields.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In V2 QBO, Custom fields are supported for Customer and Job entities only. 
Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_v2_to_v3_migration_guide#Custom_Fields#Custom_Fields

You can try V3 QBO REST APIs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/0200_custom_fields

V3 .Net Devkit (Custom Fields API Ref) -
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/custom_field_apis

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Now that you have mentioned that the custom fields are present in the Customer and Job entities I can see the field in the object that is the CustomField array in C#.

Comment: While my company is still on v2 and has not yet allotted time to upgrade to v3, is it possibly to call the REST APIs as a call from C# code to use the v3 logic on Intuite's end, all without upgrading to the v3 codebase yet?

Comment: Do you have a published app in appcenter ? Anyway you need to use v3 devkit in your codebase to use customField feature. If you use both versions in your codebase then there could be some dll conflict issues. Fyi, V2 to V3 migration deadline is - 05/15/2014. Ref https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/12/19/2014-roadmap-and-migration-dates-for-existing-developers

Comment: Thank you for this information, I will bring it to my product managers attention.